# Sharepoint 2010 - How to get/export list XSL

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, export, sharepoint-designer

On my workplace we are not allowed to used Sharepoint Designer, but I need to make a list with customized columns but still maintaining the original style and functionality.

My idea was to find a way to export the list XSL, edit it and use the option to use a custom XSL on the web part.

The thing is, I coudln't find a way to get the XSL, I only found ways to export the XML. I need a way to change how the list is displayed in a way someone else other than me can keep the list updated without needing a lot of programming knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a tough one. The technical answer is that the .xsl files start at /_layouts/xsl/main.xsl and /_layouts/xsl/local.xsl, which call more files. However, customization of a list or library will be embedded within the aspx page you're using to view it, and the xsl is "by exception" for anything different than the default templates. SPD creates a whole lot of that exception code automatically. You can try to reverse engineer the main, local, and other xsl files, but that's a herculean task. If you have a specific list and a specific goal, you could post your WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart code here or in a new question and someone with SPD could make the changes for you.

One alternative, which you might prefer since it'll leave you in control, is to set up your page to be as close to your desired design as you can, then save the aspx file locally. Using a standalone (maybe even personal) computer, install SPD and (if it comes to it) a copy of SharePoint Foundation. Add your aspx file to that, use SPD to make the changes, and copy the file back. Be sure to keep an eye on the list and view guids, since those'll change between the two, but otherwise they *should* be the same.